# How to remove legends in cartoDB?

Tags: google-maps, carto, api

I am able to add and remove cartoDB layers over my google maps but after removing layer the legend stays . how to remove that legends ?
 here is code that i used

```
document.getElementById('school').onclick = function()
        {
            var layerUrl = 'http://astrosnehakul123.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/4c13821a-e192-11e3-8f8f-0e73339ffa50/viz.json';
            if (school.checked)
            {
                        // add cartodb layer 
                      cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
                      .addTo(map,0)
                      .on('done', function(layer) 
                      {
                        layer1 = layer;
                        var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
                        sublayer.on( function(e, pos, latlng, data) {
                          cartodb.log.log(e, pos, latlng, data);


                    });

                    sublayer.on('error', function(err) {
                      cartodb.log.log('error: ' + err);
                    });

                  })
                  .on('error', function() {
                    cartodb.log.log("some error occurred");
                  });   
        }
        else{

            layer1.remove();
            layer1.clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just pass legends: false in createLayer options, like:

cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl, { legends: false })